# Merge traffic lanes in NetLogo simulation

Tags: netlogo

I want to write a NetLogo program to merge automobile lanes. Vehicles are in 4 lanes, separated by 3.5 meters (with each patch representing 1m). The center coordinates of each lane are at `ycor` values of -3.75, -7.25, -10.75 and -14.25.

Vehicles have random `xcor` values with `ycor` values at the center of one of the lanes, and are heading to the right. I want the traffic to merge so that cars driving toward the center of the map (`distancexy 0 0 <50`) all move to the same lane at ycor = -14.25 as pictured. So the car already in that lane continues forward, but the cars in other lanes turn right 45 degrees to switch lanes and then turn left by 45 degrees when they reach the pycor = -14.25 lane.

[image: What I want]

The cars turn right. However, the conditions I have set to turn the car left again when it reaches ycor = -14.25 are not working. Instead, the car continues straight ahead, crossing the lane as in the next figure.

[image: What is actually happening]

My code is:

```
ifelse ycor = -14.25
[ fd speed ]
[ rt 45
  fd speed
  ifelse ycor = -14.25
  [ lt 45
    fd speed ]
  [ fd speed ]
]
]
```

Comment: Hey, why the downvotes? This is a perfectly good question. It's a little hard to follow, but the poster is not a native English speaker.

Comment: Thank you for the picture, it is much easier to understand.

Comment: I tried to adjust it, but it still fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
if ycor = -10.75
[
  rt 45
  fd speed 
  ;;;fd 5.1
  ifelse ycor = -14.25
  [
    lt 45
    fd speed 
  ]
  [
    fd speed 
  ]
]
```

If I leave out some things that don't matter, that's:

```
if ycor = -10.75
[
  ...
  ifelse ycor = -14.25
  [
    ...
```

The `ifelse` is inside the `if`, so it only runs if ycor is -10.75. But how can `ycor` be equal to -10.75, *and* equal to -14.25? It can't, so the second condition never triggers.

Perhaps the structure you intended is:

```
ifelse ycor = -10.75
[
  ...
]
[
  ifelse ycor = -14.25
  [
    ...
```

this is how you express "if ycor is -10.75, do this; but if ycor is -14.25, do that instead".

Comment: It _might_ be a bit too much for the OP, but there is an extension that helps you avoid these multi-nested ifelse-statements. Instructions on using it here (https://github.com/qiemem/ControlFlowExtension) and download here (https://github.com/qiemem/ControlFlowExtension/releases)

Comment: I tried but could not. For vehicles running at 4 different coordinates. only vehicles in coordinates ycor = -14.25 is going straight. also other vehicles in the coordinates will be one corner 45. cheap cars still go straight ahead. how to let the car turn right 1 corner 45 which they reached the coordinates ycor 1 = -14.25 will turn left and go straight 45-degree angle. I like the new picture posted on it.

Comment: Why didn't my answer help you? I think I already answered your question. If you don't think I answered it, you need to explain how it didn't help you. We cannot write your code for you. "I tried but could not" — could not what? What did you try? Show us your new code.

Comment: I've made your way but still faulty vehicles. when the car turn right 45 degrees, then the car it ran always, the car does not have to turn left

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that ycor never exactly equals -14.25 unless it starts at -14.25. This is because the car moves forward and only checks its position after the movement, so it might move to -14.5 or -14.0 or some other value that is not -14.25. In that case, you want it turn left whenever it gets close to the -14.25 lane. Try something like this:

```
ifelse ycor = -14.25
[ fd speed ]
[ if heading = 90 [ rt 45 ]
  fd speed
  if ycor <= -12.5
  [ set heading
    set ycor -14.25
  ]
]
```

Comment: This seems like a good guess at what the problem might be. You can also try adding `print ycor` to your code so you can see exactly what the turtle's `ycor` is — that should help you understand why the condition you want to trigger isn't triggering.

Comment: I am programmed to follow proper driving lanes. I changed my code like this and it moved right lane. but it appears the state vehicle jump to coordinates ycor = -14.25 always not that vehicle to position ycor = -14.25

Comment: ifelse ycor = -14.25
    [ 
      fd speed 
    ]
    [ 
      
      rt 45 
      fd speed
      if heading = 135
      [
        fd speed
        set heading 90
        set ycor  -14.25
      ]
    ]
  ]

Answer (score 0):

```
 ifelse ycor = -14.25 [
    fd speed
    ]
    [
    rt 45
    fd speed
    ifelse ycor = -14.25
       [
       lt 45
       fd speed
       ]
       [
       fd speed
       ]
    ]
   ]
```