# simulate traffic in roundabouts

Tags: netlogo

I write algorithms for red cars turn right with direction from right to drive (heading = 90) towards heading = 180.
but its car turn right, go along too. how it came to a certain degree, it is first turned the corner to go towards heading 180

[image]

I tried some code without the right result?
[

```
 ifelse heading = 90 
  [
    if distancexy 0 0 < 30
    [
      rt 22
      fd speed
      if xcor = -2
      [
        set heading 180
        fd speed
      ]
    ]

  ]
  [
    fd speed
  ]
```

or I write code like this?

```
ifelse heading = 90 
  [
    if distancexy 0 0 < 30
    [
      rt 22
      fd speed
      if ycor = -30
      [
        set heading 180
        fd speed
      ]
    ]

  ]
  [
    fd speed
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using exact conditions like `xcor = -2` and `ycor = -30`, but these conditions are probably never true.

NetLogo turtles don't move smoothly. They jump from point to point. Imagine the turtle disappearing from its old location and reappearing in its new location. The turtle doesn't pass through all the points in between.

For example, suppose your turtle has an xcor of -2.2 and is facing east. If the turtle does `fd 1`, its new xcor will be -1.2.  But that doesn't mean code that says `xcor = -2` will run. The turtle's xcor was never -2. At one instant, it was -2.2. At the next instant, it was -1.2. So `xcor = -2` was never true.

Instead of conditions like `xcor = -2`, you probably want to be using conditions like `pxcor = -2` (true anywhere in a whole patch) or `xcor > -3 and xcor < -2` — that kind of thing.

JenB already told you this once a week ago at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34313275/86485 . I am just saying the same thing again. It's crucial you understand this.